# Why axios GET call not working for basic authentication?

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I have some users data at http://localhost:8085/api/v1/users, which is secured with basic auth. If I access this URL from browser(the URL box), it sends a `GET` request and the login(auth) prompt comes up. After filling the correct details, browser shows me the data. Even the client app like POSTMAN are working fine.

But this is not happening with the axios call. Below is the `GET` call:

```
axios
    .get(
      "http://localhost:8085/api/v1/users",
      {},
      {
        auth: {
          username: "sample@gmail.com",
          password: "pass@"
        }
      }
    )
    .then(resp => console.log(resp))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I even tried below:

```
axios({
      method: "get",
      baseURL: endpoint,
      auth: {
            username: "sample@gmail.com",
            password: "pass@"
           }
      })
      .then(resp => console.log(resp))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I think the axios is not adding Basic auth headers to the request.
What wrong am I doing here? Suggestions please.

Comment: Is the browser is logging any error message in the devtools console? If so, you probably want to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54455420/edit to edit/update the question and paste in the exact error message

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using POST instead of GET? If that doesn't work then maybe try put the username and password in a headers property not an auth property. What error do you receive?

Hope this helps.

Comment: `401` error. Actually I have done some logging at the server, to know if the server is looking into DB for the provided credentials. For browser and POSTMAN, it does look into DB, but with axios, it doesn't.